# How can I add data in a sheet in one sheet and the entire row is added to others?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I'm actually trying to do the following: 
1. Sort a sheet automatically when there is a new entry (which the script already achieves, script is shown below) lets call this Master sheet. The master sheet has the following column headers (First Name, Last Name, email Address etc.) 
2. In Sheet 1, I'm bringing in the "first Name" and "Last name" from the Master sheet. This sheet is also getting data corresponding to each name from other sheets. When the master sheet is sorted, Sheet 1 is also getting sorted, but only the Names, all other corresponding data which was associated with that name is now not corresponding correctly. So the challenge here is, when the Master file is updated, the other files should get updated the same way, by inserting a full row. This way integrity of all data in all other files can be maintained.

Is this possible? Ive bee trying to find a solution for this online for the past two weeks. any one can help, that would be great.

```
////////////////////////////////
// [START modifiable parameters]
// sheetsToSort is a regular expression -- see these sites for more info:
//    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression
//    https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax
//    https://regex101.com/
//    https://regexr.com/
var sheetsToSort = /ContactsMaster/i; // use /./i to sort all sheets
var sortByColumn = 1; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var sortAscending = true; // true for ascending, false for descending
// [END modifiable parameters]
////////////////////////////////

/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/


function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run the script in the script editor window. It runs automatically when you edit the spreadsheet.');
  }
  autoSortSheet_(e);
}


/**
* Sorts the active sheet by sortByColumn.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function autoSortSheet_(e) {
  // version 1.2, written by --Hyde 24 April 2020
  //  - move the selection back to the row that was edited
  //  - add activate() to follow the edited row -- left out in version 1.1
  //  - use e.range.getDisplayValue() instead of e.value to support dates
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde 23 April 2020
  //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/41921405
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde 21 August 2018
  //  - initial version
  //  - see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/j8xXX6_nX8c/discussion
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!sheet.getName().match(sheetsToSort)
      || e.range.columnStart > sortByColumn
      || sortByColumn > e.range.columnEnd
      || e.range.rowEnd <= sheet.getFrozenRows()) {
    return;
  }
  showMessage_('Sorting sheet...', 2);
  var value = e.range.getDisplayValue();
  sheet.sort(sortByColumn, sortAscending);
  var columnValues = sheet.getRange(sheet.getFrozenRows() + 1, sortByColumn, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getDisplayValues();
  for (var row = 0, numRows = columnValues.length; row < numRows; row++) {
    if (columnValues[row][0] === value) {
      sheet.getRange(sheet.getFrozenRows() + 1 + row, sortByColumn).activate();
      break;
    }
  }
}

/**
* Shows a message in a pop-up.
*
* @param {String} message The message to show.
* @param {Number} timeoutSeconds Optional. The number of seconds before the message goes away. Defaults to 5.
*/
function showMessage_(message, timeoutSeconds) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(message, 'Auto sort sheet', timeoutSeconds || 5);
}
```

Comment: Excel or Google sheets ?

Comment: "but only the Names, all other corresponding data which was associated with that name is now not corresponding correctly" - From where are you fetching all other corresponding data? From Master sheet?

Comment: in google sheets

Example:
Master sheet has User Data
Sheet2 - has the names First and last name being referenced from the Master Sheet in Column A & B. 
In column C - the data can either be input manually or reference from lets say Sheet 3
So the script works on the master file, and sorts the Sheet AtoZ by adding a new row. The sorted data is updated in sheet 2 automatically, but the data that was related to them are not correct as only the name columns have been updated and not the rest of the corresponding data.

Comment: So basically I need the script to add a new row in all other sheets that are referencing it once updated and sorted. Let me know if any more clarifications are needed.

Comment: If I understand you, it seems the solution would be to do the sorting of both tables AFTER "Sheet1" is updated from the "Master" . Databases usually solve this issue by inclusion of  a primary key, something I think you should consider.

Comment: Yes, I am able to sort the table automatically, but when the new data is added in the master sheet, it creates a completely new row, which is what I want. but when this happens, the data is added to other linked sheets, but only the added data is added and sorted in the linked sheet, not the entire row, which leaves all the corresponding

Comment: then expand your sort range in the linked sheet to include the added columns.